# Gulp SASS Import Paths

Tags: sass, gulp, zurb-foundation

We are using Gulp with Zurb Foundation SASS part of our front end development workflow. In our main.scss file, we are importing the _settings.scss file from Foundation to customize the variables. The main.scss file lives outside of the Foundation SASS directory forcing us to pull it in as follows:

```
@import  '../../../../../frameworks/foundation/sg/scss/settings';
```

As you can see, we have to back out of the working directory (a Wordpress Theme directory), then back into the Foundation SASS directory.

How can we minimize that path either though Gulp or some other SASS configuration file? Is there a way to set base paths somehow, or is this the desired behavior for Gulp and SASS?

Comment: You actually should copy the _settings.scss file out of the foundation directory or else it will just be overwritten when you update Foundation. But to answer your question about import paths, which gulp plugin are you using to compile the Sass?

Comment: We use gulp-sass.

Comment: **_settings.scss** and **app.scss** do NOT get overwritten upon Foundation Update.

Check out [this Foundation Forum post](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/2586-foundation-update)

Comment: Regardless, I'm looking for guidance on the SASS import paths as described above.